# How to properly display a new view and how to go back to the previous view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I'm very new to iPhone development and Objective-C. Today, I figured out how to open a new ViewController and how to return to the previous one.

Here's how I currently do this:

// In the main view controller I have a method called openSecondView that is defined like this:

```
- (void) openSecondView:(id)sender {
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
}
```

// In the SecondViewController I have a back button that calls a method called closeView that is defined like this:

```
- (void)closeView:(id)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

My question is, how do you do properly accomplish this?

Should I call **[secondView release]** after calling **presentModalViewController** or is this done some what behind the scenes? I ask this because when I was debugging I noticed that presentModalViewController doesn't seem to be a blocking code, the next few lines of code I added seem to execute immediately, without calling **dismissModalViewControllerAnimated**. Are there any consequences of calling **[secondView release]** after **presentModalViewController**?

Any help/advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call **[secondView release]** after calling **presentModalViewController**. The view controller will be retained until it is dismissed.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for the help and fast response!

Comment: And with ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) in Xcode 4.3 for iOS 5, coming out soon, you won't even have to worry about retain, release, autorelease, etc. Xcode will do it all for you. Almost not even worth it to learn memory management right now ;)

Comment: @DylanGattey  Its always important to understand memory management in iOS, especially when using third party libraries.  There's no guarantee they will support it.